# SQL Oracle set string with carriage returns

Tags: sql

I would like to set a value to a field to

```
Step 1
Blah blah blah
```

I have tried the following :

```
update myTable set display = 'Step 1' || chr(10) || 'Blah blah blah' where ...
```

However,
It does not work, I guess I am not using it correctly, but I can't find out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, you might need chr(13)||chr(10), which is carriage return and line feed